# Sending a cookie to web browser using Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, web

I am following all the suggestions online about how to send a cookie in an HTTP response in Express.

The simple way would be like so:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){

  res.cookie('foo', 'bar');

});
```

however when future requests come to the server from the same web browser, the cookie is not available in req.cookies; in other words, req.cookies['foo'] is undefined.

I have set the front-end code to use "withCredentials" for any AJAX request. Yet the cookie is still not sent to the server, or at least does not appear to be in any way.

One thing that concerns me is that when I call res.cookie('foo','bar') on the server it doesn't show up on the res object/stream as you can see here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe317re9g2frucv/Screenshot%202016-01-21%2023.49.45.png?dl=0

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using something like [`cookie-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) to parse incoming cookie headers?

Comment: yeah I am using that, and I think I might need this too?: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session sort of seems to work now, but not sure why

Comment: Just to have Express parse cookies doesn't require `cookie-session` (which is not related to cookie _parsing_, but to using cookies to store session data), just `cookie-parser`. Obviously, you would have to include it in the middleware chain before you use `req.cookies`.

Comment: Thanks, tbh I have been using cookieParser() the whole time, way up high on the middleware stack so I am very certain that wasn't the issue...I believe cookieSession() did the trick, but I would have to verify that again